# How can i find the strength of association of a set of words to a collection of sentences using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp

I have a large collection of UGC reviews and I want to find how strongly they are associated with an attraction eg The Eiffel tower.

I tried word count frequency but I got results like 'I stayed at a hotel and I could see the Eiffel tower from there' along with relevant reviews.

Is there a was with NLP to find reviews that are more closely associated with the Eiffel tower that can rank 'The view from the Eiffel tower was breathtaking' higher than 'I went to Paris and I saw all the attractions like Eiffel tower '

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an easy problem, but a simple method you could use is to compute embedding based similarity. [Spacy](https://spacy.io/) lets you do that out of the box. Let's take some examples -

```
# install spacy, will take a lot of time
# Assuming you're in a Jupyter notebook environment
!pip install spacy
!python -m spacy download en_core_web_lg


# import required library and object
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg") ##takes >1 min

# create 4 dummy reviews 
sent1 = nlp("The view from the Eiffel Tower was breathtaking")
sent2 = nlp("I went to Paris and I saw all the attractions like Eiffel Tower")
sent3 = nlp("I loved visiting the Eiffel Tower, it was beautiful")
sent4 = nlp("Eiffel Tower is a spectacular place, a must visit")

# computer similarity
print(sent1.similarity(sent2))
print(sent1.similarity(sent3))
print(sent1.similarity(sent4))
```

Output

```
0.817639160810752
0.8530533383308888
0.8638433420158428
```

So as we can see above, it'll give a higher score to reviews similar to the first one. Although the difference is not much, I think you should look more in this direction as it'll be better than word-frequency.